# Thymeleaf link is not parsed when written inside datatable's columnDefs option

Tags: datatables, thymeleaf

In the `columnDefs` option of datatable I want to render a link with `thymeleaf` :

```
datatable = table.DataTable({
    ...,
    columnDefs: [
        {
            targets: [4],
            orderable: false,
            searchable: false,
            render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                const id = row[0];
                return '<div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">'+
                            '<div class="col-sm-3"></div>'+
                            '<a th:href="@{/grilletarif/view/{id} (id='+id+')}">voir</a>'+
                            '<div class="col-sm-3"></div>'+
                            '<img class="icone_row_action" src="icones/delete.png" onclick="javascript:delete('+id+');" />'+
                            '<div class="col-sm-3"></div>'+
                        '</div>';
            }
        }

    ],
    ...
});
```

But at runtime the link is not rendered, and when I inspect the element then I get : `<a th:href="@{/grilletarif/view/{id} (id=01)}">voir</a>`

So what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thymeleaf doesn't normally parse attributes inside  tags.  And it *definitely* doesn't let you use JavaScript variables (like `const id = row[0];`) in Thymeleaf expressions like you are doing here: `th:href="@{/grilletarif/view/{id} (id='+id+')}"` (Thymeleaf doesn't know anything about JavaScript, and has already run by the time this code executes).

If you want to create this link, you'll need to use [JavaScript inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining).  Something like this for example:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
  const url = /*[[@{/grilletarif/view/}]]*/ "";
  
  datatable = table.DataTable({
    ...,
    columnDefs: [{
      targets: [4],
      orderable: false,
      searchable: false,
      render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
        const id = row[0];
        return '<div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">'+
                  '<div class="col-sm-3"></div>'+
                  '<a href="' + url + id '">voir</a>'+
                  '<div class="col-sm-3"></div>'+
                  '<img class="icone_row_action" src="icones/delete.png" onclick="javascript:delete('+id+');" />'+
                  '<div class="col-sm-3"></div>'+
                '</div>';
      }
    }],
    ...
});
</script>
```

Comment: it is `const urlGrilletarifView = [["/grilletarif/view/"]];`